# How do I perform "Build/Refresh Linked C++ Projects" from command line?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have an `Android/NDK` application and a build script which uses `gradlew.bat` to automate build/install.

The `build.gradle` uses `CMakeLists.txt` and `GLOB_RECURSE` internally in order to build the C++ files. However, if I add a new `.cpp` file to my C++ source code directory, I have to manually start Android Studio and run `"Build/Refresh Linked C++ Projects"`, otherwise the buildscript will not pick up the added `.cpp` files and I get linker errors.

I would like to have the buildscript to perform the `"Refresh Linked C++ Projects`" action, but I cannot find a Gradle task which performs this.

Does anyone know how I can perform this action, with or without Gradle, from command line?

Comment: The easiest way to refresh your CMake is to delete the `.externalNativeBuild` directory before you run gradlew. You can add such action as a custom `clean` task to **build.gradle**.

Comment: That would force a rebuild of everything every time I build, isn't it possible to just refresh the list? (Perhaps removing build.ninja or android_gradle_build.json)

Comment: Note that, with newer plugin, the directory is named `.cxx` instead of `.externalNativeBuild`

Comment: *"Refresh Linked C++ Projects"* does exactly that: full recompile. But you don't need to refresh the list every time you build. Run this custom `clean` task only when necessary. Usually, if you add cpp files, you change some other code to call them. Therefore, CMake will fail because it won't have the refreshed list of files. This would mean it's time to run `clean`.

Comment: @ViktorSehr Did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: I append a line to CMakeLists.txt in order to force an update

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be delete your CMakeCache.txt before executing other tasks. This will force the CMake to regenerate building files.

Answer (score 1):

you have to make sure you've added

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
```

on your build.gradle of your module.
and if still Refresh Linked C++ Projects is disabled you can remove .cxx and rebuild again.